# How can I syncronize these two threads properly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, mutex

I would like to synchronize different threads properly but so far I have only be able to write an inelegant solution. Can somebody kindly point out how I can improve the following code?

```cpp
typedef void (*func)();

void thread(func func1, func func2, int& has_finished, int& id) {
    has_finished--;
    func1();
    has_finished++;
    while (has_finished != 0) std::cout << "thread " << id << " waiting\n";
    std::cout << "thread" << id << "resuming\n";
    func2();
}

int main() {
    int has_finished(0), id_one(0), id_two(1);
    std::thread t1(thread, fun, fun, std::ref(has_finished), std::ref(id_one));
    std::thread t2(thread, fun, fun, std::ref(has_finished), std::ref(id_two));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
};
```

The gist of the program is described by the function `thread`.  The function is executed by two `std::thread`s. The function accepts two long-running functions `func1` and `func2` and two references of ints as arguments. **The threads should only invoke `func2` after all threads exited `func1`**. The argument `has_finished` is used to coordinate the different threads: Upon entering the function, `has_arguments` is zero. Then each `std::thread` decrements the value and invokes the long-running function `func1`. After having left `func1`, `has_finished` is incremented again. As long as this value is not at its original value of zero a thread waits. Then, each thread works on `func2`. The main function is shown at the end.

How can I coordinate the two threads better? I was thinking of using a `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` but could not figure out how to use them properly? Does somebody have any idea how I can improve the program?

Comment: It isn't obvious to me what coordination is required.  Are all threads permitted to simultaneously execute func1 and func2; but you want all threads to finish func1 before any thread starts func2?   If so, look up barrier synchronization.  If not, can you clarify the needed coordination.

Comment: No raw synchronization: you want some sort of barrier or latch primitive. E.g. Abseil has the `absl::BlockingCounter`: https://godbolt.org/z/N4oexX, and Boost has `boost::latch`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/RLZnqUrtDOoA9o7y.

Comment: @mevets : Thanks for your comment. Indeed, I want all threads to finish `func1` before beginning work on `func2`. I hope I clarified my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you've chosen won't actually work and results in undefined behavior because of the race conditions. As you surmised, you need a condition variable.

Here is a `Gate` class demonstrating how to use a condition variable to implement a gate that waits for some number of threads to arrive at it before continuing:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

struct Gate {
 public:
    explicit Gate(unsigned int count = 2) : count_(count) { }  // How many threads need to reach the gate before it unlocks
    Gate(Gate const &) = delete;
    void operator =(Gate const &) = delete;

    void wait_for_gate();

 private:
    int count_;
    ::std::mutex count_mutex_;
    ::std::condition_variable count_gate_;
};

void Gate::wait_for_gate()
{
    ::std::unique_lock<::std::mutex> guard(count_mutex_);
    assert(count > 0); // Count being 0 here indicates an irrecoverable programming error.
    --count_;
    count_gate_.wait(guard, [this](){ return this-> count_ <= 0; });
    guard.unlock();
    count_gate_.notify_all();
}

void f1()
{
    ::std::ostringstream msg;
    msg << "In f1 with thread " << ::std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    ::std::cout << msg.str();
}

void f2()
{
    ::std::ostringstream msg;
    msg << "In f2 with thread " << ::std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    ::std::cout << msg.str();
}

void thread_func(Gate &gate)
{
    f1();
    gate.wait_for_gate();
    f2();
}

int main()
{
    Gate gate;
    ::std::thread t1{thread_func, ::std::ref(gate)};
    ::std::thread t2{thread_func, ::std::ref(gate)};
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Hopefully the structure of this code looks enough like your code that you can understand what's going on here. From reading your code, it seems like you're looking for all threads to execute `func1`, then `func2`. You do not want `func2` running while any thread is executing `func1`.

That can be thought of as a gate where all the threads are waiting to arrive at the 'finished func1' location before moving on to run func2.

I tested this code on my own local version of compiler explorer.

The main disadvantage of the latch in the other answer is that it is not yet standard C++. My `Gate` class is a simple implementation of the latch class mentioned in the other answer, and it is standard C++.

The basic way a condition variable works is that it unlocks a mutex, waits for a notify, then locks that mutex and tests the condition. If the condition is true, it continues without unlocking the mutex. If the condition is false, it starts over again.

So, after the condition variable says the condition is true, you have to do whatever you need to do, then unlock the mutex and notify everybody that you've done it.

The mutex here is guarding the shared count variable. Whenever you have a shared value you should guard it with a mutex so that no thread can see that value in an inconsistent state. The condition is that threads can wait for that count to reach 0, indicating that all threads have decremented the count variable.

Answer (score 5):

Don't write this yourself. This kind of synchronization is known as a "latch" (or more generally a "barrier", and it's available through various libraries and through the C++ Concurrency TS. (It might also make it into C++20 in some form.)

For example, using [a version from Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.latches):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/thread/latch.hpp>

void f(boost::latch& c) {
    std::cout << "Doing work in round 1\n";
    c.count_down_and_wait();
    std::cout << "Doing work in round 2\n";
}

int main() {
    boost::latch c(2);

    std::thread t1(f, std::ref(c)), t2(f, std::ref(c));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Demos: with [`absl::BlockingCounter`](http://godbolt.org/z/N4oexX), with [`boost::latch`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RLZnqUrtDOoA9o7y).